# Java JVM profiling, thread status - what does "Monitor" status mean?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

[image]

I use visualVM connect a multi thread Java application, thread has 4 status, namely running, sleeping, wait, Monitor. What does this Monitoring status mean? What's the difference between wait and Monitor?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

These states are the same as mentioned in the [`Thread.State`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) enum. "Wait" means, as the documentation says:

> A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods:
>
> - Object.wait with no timeout
> - Thread.join with no timeout
> - LockSupport.park

"Monitor" is the **`BLOCKED`** state, in which the thread is waiting to obtain a lock on an object (because it's trying to enter a `synchronized` block or method while another thread already holds the associated lock).

Comment: It might be helpful anyone new to the subject (like the OP) to know that "monitor" is used as a synonym for "lock" here and in the documentation.

Comment: Is there anyway to know which synchronized object (or line of code) is the one that is causing the thread to be BLOCKED/Monitor?

Comment: @user123321 You can make a thread dump. (Button in the upper right corner of the "threads" tab.) There you can see what the thread is trying to synchronize against and which thread holds the lock.

Comment: And what's the difference between `sleeping` and `waiting` shown in the screenshot ?!

Answer (score 8):

That's not a "monitoring" status... It indicates that the thread is in the `Thread.State.BLOCKED` state. I see there is another good answer, i'll just point you to [this link](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/07/threadstate-in-java-blocked-vs-waiting.html) for deeper explanation

Answer (score 5):

Monitor will mean the thread is waiting to attain a lock on an object.  For example when one thread is running a synchronized method and another one tries to invoke it on the same object, it will not be able to until the first invocation of the method is finished.  This is because the first thread has a monitor or lock on that object, so the second one must wait until it is released.

From [Oracle Threading Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> "Synchronization is built around an internal entity known as the intrinsic lock or monitor lock. (The API specification often refers to this entity simply as a "monitor.") Intrinsic locks play a role in both aspects of synchronization: enforcing exclusive access to an object's state and establishing happens-before relationships that are essential to visibility."