# Thread status is “monitor” in Eclipse DDMS

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

What does `thread monitor` mean? The first thing I think of is that the `thread` is doing something within a `synchronized` statement. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705400/java-jvm-profiling-thread-status-what-does-monitoring-status-mean).

Comment: > "Monitor" is the BLOCKED state, in which the thread is waiting to obtain a lock on an object (because it's trying to enter a synchronized block or method while another thread already holds the associated lock).
from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705400/java-jvm-profiling-thread-status-what-does-monitoring-status-mean
Now It is clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In concurrent programming,

> a monitor is an object or module intended to be used safely by more
> than one thread
> [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)

these are the `thread` `synchronization` **mutual exclusion** and **cooperation**

**Mutual exclusion**, which is supported in the JVM via object locks, that enables multiple threads to  work independently on shared data without interfering with each other.

**Cooperation**, which is supported in the JVM via the `wait` and `notify` methods of `Object` class , enables threads to work together towards a common goal.