# What does it mean when someone says - "a thread enters an object's monitor"?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

What exactly is a monitor?. Do all objects have monitors or only objects on which synchronization is done have monitors?. What is entering/moving out of monitors?.. How are they stored in memory? i.e, are they part of the object they are related to?.. Thanks in advance... PS : I am referring to Java multithreading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JVM profiling, thread status - what does "Monitor" status mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705400/java-jvm-profiling-thread-status-what-does-monitor-status-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each object, not only  synchronized.

[JLS chapter 17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

> The Java programming language provides multiple mechanisms for communicating between threads. The most basic of these methods is synchronization, which is implemented using monitors. **Each object in Java is associated with a monitor**, which a thread can lock or unlock. Only one thread at a time may hold a lock on a monitor. Any other threads attempting to lock that monitor are blocked until they can obtain a lock on that monitor. A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation.

Comment: ok.. I know this is dumb... Is there any way I can see the contents of a monitor or say- the monitor itself?.